# Override Internal Style tag in External CSS file

Tags: html, css

I searched a lot, but i couldn't find any answer, and i am wondering is there any way to override **internal style tag(with !important)** , in External css file?
no change to html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
   <style>
     p {
       color: red !important;
     }
   </style>
 </head>
<html>
<body >    
   <p>how to override internal style?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any way to override the style and give the p tag, other color?

i tried this css file :

```
p {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just write a rule with higher specificity, and use `!important` again on the value in there ...?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't override.

Comment: You need to show what exactly you tried, otherwise how could we possibly tell what went wrong.

Comment: It's probably better if you use classes, rather than targeting specific elements. If you give your CSS class a reasonable name, that shows better intent. For instance `<style>.warning { colour: red !important; } </style>` and later on `<p class="warning">Blah</p>` that way, there are more options available to you, and only the HTML elements that you want to target are affected.

Comment: @CBroe I updated the question with css file code.

Comment: @MehdiM — You ignored the bit where CBroe said you needed a rule with higher specificity.

Comment: That's only half of what I said, you did nothing to increase the _specificity_ of that rule. And with the _same_ specificity as the rule from the style element that comes later, the latter of course wins.

Comment: @CBroe Now I get it, and it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it had been told in the comments, its possible with higher specificity in the css file :
and no need to change html file.

```
body p {
   color: aqua !important;
}
```

Thank you all.